Continuously Getting 'A device attached to the system is not functioning' Error When Processing Dimension in SSAS
I am experiencing a persistent issue when trying to process the 'City' dimension in SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) using Visual Studio 2019 connected to SSMS 18. Despite multiple attempts and adjustments, I consistently receive the error:

A device attached to the system is not functioning.

Here are the key details of my setup and what I've tried:
Environment:

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18: Manages Wide World Importers (WWI) database.
Visual Studio 2019: Used for SSAS projects, connecting via SQL Server Native Client 11.0.
Analysis Services: Configured with two instances, one for multidimensional and one for tabular models, using service accounts with comprehensive permissions.
Database: World Wide Importers
Operating System: Windows 11

Issue Details:

The error occurs exclusively when processing the 'City' dimension. Deployment of the project is successful in Visual Studio but run into this error when processing my first dimension.
The system does not indicate hardware failures or resource limitations (CPU, disk, memory).

Screenshot:

Troubleshooting Steps Tried:

Checked and confirmed service account permissions.
Ensured SQL Server configurations allow adequate resources and proper network settings.
Reviewed and tried altering SQL Server Native Client and OLE DB provider settings for compatibility.

I was hoping to process the dimension successfully without errors, expecting the system to handle this without such failures.
Could anyone suggest what might be causing this specific error and how to resolve it? Is there a known issue with device configuration or SSAS setup that leads to such an error?"

Aside... SQL Server Native Client 11.0 hasn't received any updates since SQL Server 2012 days, when it was deprecated, and Microsoft doesn't even ship it any more as of SQL Server 2022. You should consider using different drivers, such as ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (or 18), or OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server.

SSMS 18 (SQL Server Management Studio) is just a tool for managing SQL Server instances, it doesn't host any databases itself. What version of SQL Server are you actually using? i.e.: what's the output of SELECT @@VERSION when executed against the instance?

Is your SSAS instance using the same locale as your SQL Server instance? e.g.: if SQL Server is installed using 0x0409 en-US (1033) then SSAS needs to be using 0x0409 en-US (1033) as well.

Hi, @AlwaysLearning! I am aware SQL Server Native Client 11.0 hasn't received any updates since SQL Server 2012. The reason I am using it in combination with SQL Server 2019 is because I am following a book called "Hands-On SQL Server 2019 Analysis Services". The end goal is to create an interactive BI environment for Wide World Importers, enabling data-driven insights and strategic decision-making through comprehensive sales, orders, and transactions analysis using the WideWorldImportersDW database. But I cannot get it to process the first dimension I run.

In addition to the A device attached to the system is not functioning errors do you also see any warnings similar to The 'someNumberHere' locale is not supported?

No, not at all @AlwaysLearning. I also forgot to mention that both my SQL server and SSAS are both using 0x0409 en-US (1033).
